# Script Mediator setPayloadJSON formatting numeric string as Number

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are using a script mediator to create a payload to our aggregation mediator, we have a numeric string that as typed as string, but mc.setPayloadJSON always formatting string as number in json output.

Desired:

> ```
>         {
>             "id": "29fcf271-a077-4bd9-abb0-f6e7f8bef801",
>             "scheme": "EMAIL",
>             "date": "30/10/1986",
>             "name": "Name",
>             "document": "36105126875",
>             "type": "CODE",
>             "value": "c*********a@******.com",
>             "mat": "553179"
>         },
> ```

Result:

> ```
>         {
>             "id": "29fcf271-a077-4bd9-abb0-f6e7f8bef801",
>             "scheme": "EMAIL",
>             "date": "30/10/1986",
>             "name": "Name",
>             "document": 36105126875,
>             "type": "CODE",
>             "value": "c*********a@******.com",
>             "corporateid": 553179
>         },
> ```

JS Example:

```
var payload = { "methods": [{ "reference": id, "type": "CODE", "value": email_mask, "scheme": "EMAIL", "name": "Name", "document": numdoc, "mat": mat, "date": dt_birth }] }
```

mc.setPayloadJSON(payload);

There was a way to formatting numeric string as string with script mediator mc.setPayloadJSON?

Thank you